# How to set Media Url of MediaPart? Orchard MediaLibraryPickerField MediaParts is null

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am trying to automatically assign the MediaPart.MediaUrl to a custom image upon published. But..
MediaPickerField MediaParts is always null.

```
        OnPublished<BlogPostPart>((context, part) =>
        {
            ContentPart cp = part.ContentItem.Parts.Skip(13).First();
            MediaLibraryPickerField field = cp.Fields.FirstOrDefault() as MediaLibraryPickerField;
            if (field != null) { 
               // this part throws an object null reference exception since fields.MediaParts is null
               foreach(Orchard.MediaLibrary.Models.MediaPart mp in  field.MediaParts){

               }
            }
        });
```

How to programically set the MediaUrl from the code on the event on publish? I am using Orchard 1.8

Answer (score 0):

MediaParts is implemented as a lazy field so that the value isn't fetched unnecessarily. The loader for the lazy field is set-up by the handler for the field, during the `Loaded` event.

A content item that has just been created has gone through `Creating`, `Created`, and `Publishing` before it goes into `Published`. That means that the media library picker fields's media part collection is not available at this point.

What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Also, you should never rely on the order or number of parts on a content item, so that `Skip(13)` is not the right way of getting to the part you want.

Comment: This is what I want to do-> When I publish a blog post (from live writer or from word), I want to make the first image (if any) the default image of the media library picker field. Later if I want I can then go and change the image to another one. So on published event I am trying to set the media url extracted from the blog post. I agree skip(17) was put just for debugging :)

Comment: Well, the good thing is that you can know that the collection of media parts is empty. Try to assign an empty collection to the property, then add your media, and re-publish (careful about infinite loops).

Comment: I my case I needed to get the url and I was stuck for several hours, the workaround that I found was to get the MediaPart via ContentManager using the id provided by the field that it's available at that point.

`MediaLibraryPickerField photoMediaPicker = photoField as MediaLibraryPickerField;`
`MediaPart photoMediaPart = _orchardServices.ContentManager.GetMany<MediaPart>(photoMediaPicker.Ids, VersionOptions.Published, QueryHints.Empty).ToList().FirstOrDefault();`


(OnUpdated handler triggered by OnPublished).
Hope this helps for somebody with the same issue.

Regards.